# Simple free web hosting to place my web page

Tags: free, web-hosting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find web hosting that meets my requirements?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20838/how-to-find-web-hosting-that-meets-my-requirements)

please advise me simple web hosting. Just I want to upload webpage (simple) which I created and I don't need wizards or generators.

Answer (score 1):

Try 000webhost.com or freehostia.com.

Answer (score 0):

You can try altervista.org
give you a free third level domain

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Google App Engine](http://code.google.com/appengine/) to host static or dynamic pages.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Zymic and Xtreemhost. They offer 5gb of free space.